# Field Extension from R(i) to R

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that [$\Bbb R$($^{4}\sqrt i$):$\Bbb R$]=2.
I know that $\Bbb C$=$\Bbb R$(i) is algebraically closed and that $\Bbb R\subset\Bbb C\subset\Bbb R(^{4}\sqrt i)$, meaning we can apply Lagrange to determine [$\Bbb R$($^{4}\sqrt i$):$\Bbb R$]=[$\Bbb R$($^{4}\sqrt i$):$\Bbb C$]$\bullet$[$\Bbb C$:$\Bbb R$]. I'm having trouble identifying the degree of the extension [$\Bbb R$($^{4}\sqrt i$):$\Bbb C$].

Comment: The complex number $\cos(\pi/8)+i\sin(\pi/8)$ is a fourth root of $i$. By Moivré.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}(i)$, you don't have much left to do. You also know that $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, i.e. contains all roots of all polynomials with complex coefficients.

Now show that $i^{1/4}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{R}$ by explicitly giving some polynomial of which it is a root. Then you know that $i^{1/4}\in\mathbb{C}$ and you can conlude.